# How to maintain AnonymousUser session with Django test client

Tags: django

I have a Django `TestCase` where I would like to test an `AnonymousUser` visiting the same page twice. I would like to test that an action is only taken on the first visit, which is achieved by storing some data in the session upon the first visit.

I can't use `TestCase.client`, because it uses a new `AnonymousUser` for each request and they have a new session.

```
from django.test import TestCase


class MyTestCase(TestCase):
    def test_my_test(self):
        self.client.get(url)

        response = self.client.get(url)

        self.assertTrue(...)
```

Comment: I'm not really following why that is a problem for using `self.client`?

Comment: I'll try to edit and explain better, thanks. My problem is that if there is no logged in user than every request made with self.client uses a new AnonymousUser. In the real word, even if I am not logged in, if I move around on the site I will be one AnonymousUser and this is what I want to simulate in the test. There is a page, which should do some backend action only the first time an AnonymousUser visits (not the second) and I want to write a test for this page.

Comment: Is this more clear at all?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. It will maintain session across the two requests with user being the same `AnonymousUser` for both requests.

```
from django.test import TestCase


class MyTestCase(TestCase):
    def test_my_test(self):
        request = RequestFactory().get(url)
        request.user = AnonymousUser()
        request.session = SessionStore()
        MyView.as_view()(request)

        response = MyView.as_view()(request)

        self.assertTrue(...)
```